# Hooking R from within Excel - DCOM? R add in for Excel?

Tags: excel, r, dcom

In the past I have used a DCOM connection to call R functions from Excel and from VBA inside of Excel. I just got a new laptop and have been looking for the install files for the R add in for Excel. I find references to it all over the place but they all point to R (D)COM Server project's home page at http://sunsite.univie.ac.at/rcom. That URL has been down now for some time. Is there another way to get the same functionality with another method? Is there a new project page?

I've never tried to use the DCOM server without the Excel Add-in. Is that a possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by installing [RExcelInstaller](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RExcelInstaller/index.html) from [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org) via

```
> install.packages("RExcelInstaller")
```

and take it from there.

Comment: Yep, that's the way it *used* to work. I install RExcelInstaller and then try to run installstatconnDCOM() and it barfs saying "the download site http://rcom.univie.ac.at seems to be currently unreachable" The command installRExcel() results in the same response.

Comment: Methinks you want to contact the package authors, or at least the dedicated mailing list rather than posting here. YMMV.

Comment: Good point Dirk. I contacted Erich Neuwirth and he said they were having some server problems but they are still maintaining the project. I was able to download everything as expected this morning.